# Does healing a hurt ally increase ÜberCharge rate?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Does healing a hurt ally increase the ÜberCharge rate of a medic?

If so, how much does it increase it by?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The charge rate is doubled. However, this bonus is automatically applied during setup time, even on fully overhealed teammates, and does not stack. Thus, teammates damaging themselves is not necessary during setup time.

For the [Medigun](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Medigun):

> The ÜberCharge meter will fill faster, at 2.5%/second, when healing injured teammates or teammates whose health is not at 150%, at 1.25%/second.

The [Kritzkrieg](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Kritzkrieg) builds charge 25% faster, so the rate for healing injured teammates is 3.125% and for healthy teammates is 1.5625%.

Note that this refers to ÜberCharge. All that mumbo jumbo about faster healing rates depending on how long someone has been injured, refers to the rate of HP healed rather than ÜberCharge rate.

Comment: Note that by now most people know this, and the main reason demomen set off sticky bombs under their feet during setup time is for the lulz while they're stuck in the setup room...

Comment: @Shadur when the game was new, you did not get the faster charge time during setup, so having a soldier or demoman to self-damage was required in order to have an ubercharge ready at the start of a map.  I think some people still think this is the case, but you are right, mostly it's people being bored.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Also, the longer an ally goes without taking damage, the faster you will heal them.

Comment: This is incorrect. The factor that determines how fast an ally gets healed is the time since they were last *damaged* (ramping up at 10 seconds to triple speed at 15 seconds since last damage), and it increases at all times, *even while healing*.

Comment: (I have since edited the answer.)